# Laravel Intervention - Unable to init from given binary data

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, intervention

I am using `"intervention/image": "^2.5"` in one of my projects. It is working well except for one part of the code where im retrieving an image.

I keep getting a `Unable to init from given binary data` error and i cant figure out why.

The file exists but i cant figure it out.

My code is as follows;

```php
$path = '/image-storage/492/1/testimage.jpg';
$file = Storage::get($path);
ob_end_clean();

return Image::make($file)->response();
```

Below is my `filesystem.php` config for local

```php
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
],
```

Comment: can you please share your 'config/filesystems.php' file for better understanding?

Comment: if the "image-storage" folder is inside public folder in storage than you must pass public in your path like 'public/image-storage/492/1/testimage.jpg' . Hope it will help

Comment: What is the path of the file relative to the storage folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Storage::get($path)** returns file contents as a string which may not be cast to valid binary data for **Image::make()** to be able to read.

You can try by passing the path to the image to the **make** method

```php
//If testimage.jpg is located at storage/app/image-storage/492/1
$path = storage_path('app/image-storage/492/1/testimage.jpg');

//if testimage.jpg is located at storage/app/public/image-storage/492/1/, then
//$path = storage_path('app/public/image-storage/492/1/testimage.jpg');

return Image::make($path)->response();
```

OR you can create a new `Illuminate\Http\File` instance and then pass it to the **make** method

```php
//If testimage.jpg is located at storage/app/image-storage/492/1
$path = storage_path('app/image-storage/492/1/testimage.jpg');

//if testimage.jpg is located at storage/app/public/image-storage/492/1/, then
//$path = storage_path('app/public/image-storage/492/1/testimage.jpg');

$file = new \Illuminate\Http\File($path);

Image::make($file)->response();
```

Intervention image accepts binary data or **SplFileInfo** instance. `Illuminate\Http\File` extends `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File` which extends `\SplFileInfo`.

[Intervention Image - Reading Images](https://image.intervention.io/v2/usage/overview#reading-images)